# Fortran accuracy and speed vs. C

Tags: c, fortran90, gfortran

This subject has probably been discussed hundreds of times. I'm not trying to claim 
any language is worse or better. I'm just trying to learn how to accelerate my C codes.
So here are two codes to calculate Pi.

The first is in Fortran90:

```
program calcpi
implicit none
integer :: i
real*8 :: pi

pi=0.0
do i = 0,1000000000
   pi = pi + 1.0/(4.0*i+1.0)
   pi = pi - 1.0/(4.0*i+3.0)
end do

pi = pi * 4.0

write(*,*) pi

end program calcpi
```

The second is in C:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define STEPCOUNTER 1000000001
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
long i;
double pi=0;
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+: pi)
for ( i=0 ; i < STEPCOUNTER; i++){
   /*pi/4=1/11/3+1/51/7+...
   To avoid the need to continually change
   the sign (s=1; in each step s=s*-1 ),
   we add two elements at the same time.*/

   pi+=1.0/(i*4.0+1.0);   
   pi-=1.0/(i*4.0+3.0);   
//   pi = pi +  1.0/(i*4.0+1.0);
//   pi = pi -  1.0/(i*4.0+3.0);
}

 pi=pi*4.0;
 printf("Pi=%lf\n",pi);
return 0;
}
```

I am compiling both codes with gcc version 4.4.4 on a CentOS 6 machine.

```
[oz@centos ~]$ gfortran calcpi.f90 -o calcpi.fort.o
[oz@centos ~]$ gfortran calcpi.c -o calcpi.c.o
```

The CPU is Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU 5160  @ 3.00GHz.

So, here is how much time it takes to run each code:

```
[oz@centos ~]$ time ./calcpi.c.o 
Pi=3.141593

real    0m33.270s
user    0m33.261s
sys     0m0.000s
[oz@centos ~]$ time ./calcpi.fort.o 
   3.1415926553497115     

real    0m27.220s
user    0m27.208s
sys     0m0.001s
```

Fortran is about 20% Faster. 
My Question is what are the best compiler flags to speed up, but still keep the stability and accuracy ?

(And yes, I know about man gcc, I want to know about users' opinions).

Thanks for your opinions.

Result, without OpenMP pragma:

```
[oz@centos ~]$ time ./calcpi.c.o 
Pi=3.141593

real    0m32.892s
user    0m32.885s
sys     0m0.001s
```

Other results, without changing the code itself:

```
$ gcc -O2 calcpi.c -o calcpi.c.o
$ time ./calcpi.c.o 
Pi=3.141593

real    0m21.085s
user    0m21.078s
sys     0m0.000s
$ gfortran -O2 calcpi.c -o calcpi.c.o
$ time ./calcpi.fort.o 
   3.1415926553497115     

real    0m26.892s
user    0m26.888s
sys     0m0.000s
```

Comment: What is the result without the OpenMP pragmas ? Also, did you try to disassemble the code to see where the differences are ?

Comment: A general optimisation might be multiplying STEPCOUNTER by 4, then incrementing i by 4 each time so that you can remove the (i*4.0) multiplication? Also using integers int he denominator should help. Either way, to compare the two samples I think Alexandre's comment about viewing the generated instructions would give the best insight.

Comment: As LaceySnr says, to use integers for the denominator, you can use the type `uint32_t` for `i`, just as long as `STEPCOUNTER` doesn't go above `2**30 - 4`. Then it's `pi+=1.0/(i+1)` assuming you've also changed the loop to `( i=0 ; i < 4*STEPCOUNTER; i += 4)`. You could even start `i` at `1` so that the `pi+=...` doesn't need the addition in there. It would be interesting to see whether those changes make a difference with optimization enabled. They will not necessarily help but it's worth trying.

Comment: Thanks for your answers! The -O2 flag does make improvement, and turns the picture over. That is even before I went into optimizing the code itself. That is impressive.

Comment: Also, you'll get slightly better accuracy for this series if you start adding from the smallest terms, rather than the largest. I suppose that the OMP parallel means you don't necessarily know what order they're added, but I suspect that if you write the loop to add them in order of increasing magnitude then OMP is more likely to actually add them in an order approximating to that.

Comment: Uses -O3 or -Os to optimize the binary.

Comment: @steve you mean decrement in the loop instead of increment?

Comment: I'm not sure it factors into the comparison, but I think you'll need to use the -fopenmp flag for the OpenMP pragma in your C code to have an effect.

Comment: If you remove the `pi = pi * 4.0;` at the end, you can change the loop calculations to `pi += 1.0 / (i + 0.25); pi -= 1.0 / (i + 0.75);`.

Comment: @steve I did : for ( i=0 ; STEPCOUNTER > 0; i--) ... now the code takes well over 1 minute to run. Are you sure about this ?

Comment: @Oz123: `STEPCOUNTER > 0` is always true. You need `for (i = STEPCOUNTER - 1; i != -1; --i)`

Comment: @steve, yes, obviously I should not code before launch break :-) so hasty ... Thanks. It is a bit slightly faster.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Modifying the Fortran program such that it corresponds to the C version by making all calculations in double precision:

```
program calcpi
  implicit none
  integer :: i
  integer, parameter :: p = selected_real_kind(15)
  real(p) :: pi

  pi=0.0_p
  do i = 0,1000000000
     pi = pi + 1.0_p/(4.0_p*i+1.0_p)
     pi = pi - 1.0_p/(4.0_p*i+3.0_p)
  end do

  pi = pi * 4.0_p

  write(*,*) pi

end program calcpi
```

Compiling with -O2 using GCC 4.4.3 on x86_64-linux-gnu on a Xeon X3450 (2.67 GHz) I get the following timings:

```
$ time ./calcpi_c 
Pi=3.141593

real    0m13.903s
user    0m13.860s
sys 0m0.010s
$ time ./calcpi_fort 
   3.1415926530880767     

real    0m13.876s
user    0m13.840s
sys 0m0.000s
```

IOW, they are more or less indistinguishable. Which is about what one would expect for such a simple example.

Comment: ! Thanks, I still have a lot to learn in Fortran too! Your answer is definitely adding to my soup! I'll wait a bit more before I accept your answer just to see if some has some more insight.